# reading the output of netstat for tcp

Tags: ssh, tcp, sshd, netstat

If I `ssh root@server -R 5901:localhost:5900` and `netstat -an` I get:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)                                           │
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State                       │
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                      │
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN                      │
```

Whereas if I allow `GatewayPorts yes` in my ssh_config and do the same I get

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

(and my service is reachable from the outside network)

How do you read the format `::1:5901` (as opposed to `:::5901`)?

edit :

*How do you read that one is not open to the public network?*

0.0.0.0 means "all IP addresses on the local machine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IPv6 terminology, `::1` is the loopback address (e.g. `127.0.0.1` in IPv4 terminology).

It is essentially `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` (or more precisely, but uninterestingly, `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`) with all the 0's collapsed down into `::1`.  It is functionally equivalent to the IPv4 `127.0.0.1` and performs the same role.

So in the first output, the `tcp6` line is listening on the IPv6 loopback address, not on all addresses, and hence is not visible externally.

The second example (`:::5901`) shows the unspecified IPv6 address `::`, followed by an additional colon and the port number. This is functionally equivalent to the unspecified IPv4 address with port in `0.0.0.0:5901` and hence is open to the network over any IPv6 address.

Comment: excellent ! makes sense.. do you have a fetish/preferred book on those issues by any chance ?

Comment: @nicolas no, IPv6 is horrible and reading about it is like putting salt into your eyes.  However, the [Wikipedia overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) is usually helpful for the basics.

Comment: (Just a comment, as this was edited out: Presenting an IPv6 address with all those leading zeros is not "more precisely", but not recommended. [RFC 5952, section 4.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4.1) says quite strictly, "Leading zeros MUST be suppressed." :-) While this verbose form must be accepted by any software that handles IPv6 addresses, it must not be used in textual representations.)

Comment: @EightBitTony ahah :) There are fine and precious japanese salts though... but I guess you dont want it in your eyes :) thanks for the tip, i was disoriented with many other things to have the good reflex...

Comment: @Dubu good to know